# How to makea specific SSRS 2012 report on Sharepoint 2010 publicly accessible

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a couple of reports that are sitting on a Sharepoint site that I need to make available to users outside of the organisation that I'm working in. So they will need to login in a .com portal etc to view these reports. at the moment we only have the Sharepoint reporting services running.

How I'm looking for the easiest way to achieve this.  Could be depoly the reports needed on native mode server and have the native portal front end accesible for appropriate users, or should we be looking to build a tailored frontend to pull the specified reports directly from their sharepoint location.

any recomendations be greatly appreciated
mark

Comment: Are the reports time sensitive? If not, you could set up schedules to publish them somewhere for your external users.

Comment: Hi Chris, The majority would be on demand. For eg a clientwanting to know their current holdings. In general, these would be graphical reports that we would like them to login to.